# Facebook page multiple tabs with one app mystery

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

Please read the question carefully before you answer as it is a bit confusing.

I recently saw that Pagemodo gives the option to have multiple tabs on a single page as many times as you want which they call as "UNLIMITED TABS" in their plan options. So this means that if we want multiple welcome tabs on a page that can be done. Technically you can create only one page tab with one application. To have multiple tabs you will need multiple apps.

Now the question is how is it possible?

Even if i have multiple apps, while showing the page tab i can fetch the data about the tab from a db using "page id" as this is the only thing i have in the signed request. How do they get to know which page it is (ok we can get it from signed request) and which app it is out of those multiple apps that were created so that they render data accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful your not falling for marketing speak.

Pagemodo likely manages a defined number of apps (which may be a very large number) and is allowing you to install them onto any page you manage giving you in essence unlimited uses.

The backend is all managed via end points for each of the apps and the signed request.

Answer (score 0):

I found how it may be possible.

This is a nice place to get an idea of the problem i came up with:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=90792

After thinking about it i came up with the following solution that though you do not have a way to get the application id till you are not authenticated using signed request or any other data provided by facebook. But you can still get it via the page tab url. 
So if i have an app with tab url as: http://www.example.com/tab.php, we can pass the app id via http://www.example.com/tab.php?id=APPID

Solves the purpose pretty well.